# How can I do a subtotal on Excel grouping by month

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I'm using the following formula to sum filtered/hidden rows, which works great...

```
=SUBTOTAL(109;J2:J3105)
```

However, I'm can't find a way to apply this logic so that the subtotal will only add rows with a certain month. This doesn't work...

```
=SUBTOTAL(109;SUM(IF(MONTH(E2:E3105)=1;J2:J3105;0)))
```

Comment: What result are you getting with that formula?

Comment: it errors out...